# Passing variables in ansible, windows

Tags: ansible

I am using the below code to find file older than some n days.
For each application I need to pass different paths as variable. For some it will be one path, for others it might be three paths.
So for the application with one path, if I didn't define the other paths, it will show as undefined variable. How to overcome this?

```
 - name: Find files older than n days
   win_find:
    paths:
    - "{{[path1}}"
    - "{{[path2}}"
    - "{{[path3}}"
    age: "{{age}}"
   register: files
```

Comment: You can overcome this by using one variable that is a list. Have a look at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-simple-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me by using one variable in a list.

```
vars:
 paths:
  - D:\path1
  - D: \path2 
- name: Find files older than n days
   win_find:
    paths: "{{paths}}"
    age: "{{age}}"
   register: files  
``
```